# Large dataset, how to select a particular range

Tags: matlab, matrix, range, selection

I have a dataset that consists of 30000 rows and 48 columns, and I wish to select rows 1:24100 for columns 1:3, 5 and 8:10. How can I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Using Matlab as programming language

Comment: Google "Matrix Indexing in MATLAB"

Answer (score 0):

Using [matrix indexing](https://mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html), you give give the row indices first, and then the column indices. These indices can be vectors.

```
data = rand(30000,48);
selection = data(1:24100, [1:3 5 8:10])
```